# PHP sendmail_path Flags -- Not working correctly?

Tags: php, sendmail, email-headers

I recently switched hosts and am having an issue with the mail() function.

On my previous host, I could define the from address through the header by doing this:

```
mail("test@email.com","subject","message","From: fake@email.com");
```

On the new host however, it ignores the From header. Instead it sends from a default email account something@something.myhost.com.

In php.ini, the sendmail_path is set as follow: sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

As far as I can tell from researching, this should allow me to set the from address in the header.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", "fake@email.com");
```

The `set_ini` dynamically sets the configuration option, in this case the `sendmail_from`

"**Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.**"

is the definition for `ini_set` found at :[PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)